# Nexus/Artifactory like maven proxy for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven, nexus

I am currently working on a testsuite for a relatively large test-project. It's the test-harness of the flexmojos project. I wrote down how the testsuite works in general here: https://flexmojos.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FLEXMOJOS/How+the+flexmojos-test-harness+works

My problem now is that currently a lot of stuff is copied to the test-local-repo in the initialize phase of the build, but not everything (Listing up everything would result in a huge pom). The build is configured to look in my main local repo first and if it can't find it there, to download it. So when the build runs, a lot of stuff is loaded from remote repos. Unfortunately this is done every time the testsuite is executed.

What I would like to do, would be to setup some sort of local nexus/artifactory-like plugin, that serves things from my main local-repo and fetches things it can't find from my main mavens repos (configured in my main settings.xml). I would now like to use this plugin to serve as main repo for my build, so the artifacts it needs are downloaded only the first time the testsuite is executed.

Please tell me there is such a thing available :-)

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The best thing i know is the [Mock Repository Manager Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/mrm-maven-plugin/) which simulates a proxy. The best combination is usually for integration testing of Maven plugins which usually using [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/). But i think the mrm plugin should fit you needs.

Comment: This seems to look exactly like what I was looking for. How does the plugin react if the "client" requests a plugin that is not provided by it's host local repo?